# Actionscript 3.0: Help Linking Document Class To And Audio Slider Class

Tags: actionscript-3

so I've been going at actionscript 3 for a couple weeks now but I'm still a complete newb. The most difficulty I've had is linking classes to my document class. For example, I'll have a nice great class that does things wonderfully (I could just insert it as the document class of another FLA and it would provide all the functionality I need for that specific function), but now when I have to insert it as a regular class...I guess "subclassing" the document class, all goes to hell.

I know you have to change variables and instantiate things to get it to work and I sort of understand that, but it sometimes it just gets way over my head and I feel like their should be a simple solution if I ALREADY HAVE a full working class. Seems that all too often there's a billion things I need to switch around.

Anyways, I have a specific example I'm hoping someone could help explain and walk me through a bit. I went online and found some code for a slider, then spent the last few hours editing it to contain the mp3 I want, loop it, etc. etc. Now it works great on a designated FLA...I just run it as the document class and up pops a designed audio slider that changes the volume, loops and everything. Now I want to add this slider into a simple game I've been working on, but just have NO idea where to start or what to do. For now I'll keep it simple though.

Say I just have my blank document class and my audio slider class. Now when I run my game, it runs the document class of course, and from there, I want it to run my audio slider class directly. I think if I just solve this I will be able to implement it into my game. So here is my blank document class and my audio slider class! Thanks for the help!

WHAT I'VE TRIED

I attempted to create public variables in the document class for the sprite and the slider, then create a new sprite/slider once the document class runs. I thought that to be on the right track, but then it started looking like I was going to have to do that for almost all the variables in the audio slider class. I also thought...well why can't I just run Volume() in the Document Class? Still confusing me a little why that doesn't work, but it doesn't.

Blank Document Class

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;


    public class ASDocumentClass extends MovieClip {

        public function ASDocumentClass() {

        }
    }

}
```

and here is the audio slider class

```
package {

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.Graphics;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import flash.media.SoundChannel;
        import flash.media.SoundTransform;
        import flash.geom.Rectangle;

        public class Volume extends Sprite {

                public var snd:Sound = new Sound();
                public var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
                //URLRequest=new URLRequest("solitude.wav");
                //Make sure you pass URLRequest an audio file on your computer.
                public var req:BackgroundMusic = new BackgroundMusic();
                public var boundary:Rectangle;
                public var sprite:Sprite;
                public var slider:Sprite;
                public var xPos:Number=stage.stageWidth/2;
                public var yPos:Number=stage.stageHeight/2;
                public var vol:Number;

                /*
                Our request is loaded into the sound object and plays through
                our channel. Volume is initially set at 50% and passed as a
                transformation to our our channels soundTransform property
                (a fancy way of saying volume). The init() function is called.  
                */

                public function Volume() {
                        channel=req.play();
                        channel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onBackgroundMusicFinished,false,0,true );
                        vol=.5;
                        channel.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(vol);
                        init();
                }

                /*

                The init function creates and draws a rectangle and circle
                to the stage and centers them based on the height and
                width of the stage. In addition, a rectangle object is
                created to 'contain' the sliding circle, like an imaginary box.
                We pass -100 as the x value because it is added relative
                to our sprite. If we set its x value at 0, or the sprites default x
                value,the boundary would stop and start at the slider sprite. Change
                -100 to 0 in the rectangle object to get a better idea of its use.

                */

                public function init():void {
                        sprite = new Sprite();
                        sprite.graphics.beginFill(0x999999);
                        sprite.graphics.drawRect(xPos,yPos,200,5);
                        sprite.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(sprite);
                        sprite.x-=sprite.width/2;
                        slider = new Sprite();
                        slider.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                        slider.graphics.drawCircle(xPos,yPos, 20);
                        slider.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(slider);
                        slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragSlider);
                        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopSlider);
                        boundary=new Rectangle(-100,0,200,0);
                }

                /*

                dragSlider runs when the use holds the mouse button down. A
                startDrag method is used on our sprite where we specify boundary
                as our dragging limits. A new event handler designed
                to change the mouse volume is subsequenlty called per frame, where
                the slider.x property determines volume.

                */

                public function dragSlider(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        slider.startDrag(false,boundary);
                        slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dragSlider);
                        slider.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeVolume);
                }

                /*

                Stops dragging and removes the event listener to save on space. Again,
                volume will be based on the sliders current x position, which is
                constantly being recalculated per frame because we used an
                ENTER_FRAME event.

                */

                public function stopSlider(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        slider.stopDrag();
                        slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopSlider);
                }

                /*

                This function is constantly recalculating the vol variable
                based on the sliders x position, relative to the length of
                our rectangle. Creates a decimal range from 0 to 1, where 1
                represents 100% volume and 0 represents mute. Anything exceeding
                100% causes distortion.

                */

                public function changeVolume(event:Event):void {
                        vol=.5+Math.round(slider.x)/200;
                        channel.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(vol);
                }

                public function onBackgroundMusicFinished(event:Event):void
                {
                    channel = req.play();
                    channel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onBackgroundMusicFinished );
                }

        }

}
```

Comment: I hope someone comes along and helps you but I also wanted to ask if you had considered using other IDEs for developing AS3 code?  If you're not comfortable with the stage and dealing with instances in multiple (and sometimes strange) ways perhaps you're better off using Flex/FlashBuilder (IDE not framework necessarily) or FDT (Flash Developer Tools) or something like that where everything is just code (since it seems you're pretty comfortable with that part).  If you use the timeline for animation etc. you could still do that an import animation swfs for use in code.

Comment: No I haven't. I mean....honestly I've only been at this a few weeks and I'm MUCHHH better than when I began. I mean I almost have a fully working game. So I don't think using this framework is a particularly bad one, I just think it has a steep learning curve. I often like the structure of it, but understanding it is going to take a few more weeks I think, which is fine. I think learning another IDE would be a bit wasteful at this point. There's nothing wrong with the structure in my opinion and it works great when used properly.

Comment: Sorry @John think you misread my communication or I mis-wrote it... I wasn't saying to use some other framework, or language, just saying maybe using Flash IDE (one of two main tools Adobe has for writing AS3 isn't the best way to go since you seem very code centric and the IDE tends to be more visually focused (with temporal visual translation via the timeline), rather than being free of time and based just on events/logic in code.  Anyhow if you're set on staying in Flash for now that's understandable.  In either case you have to deal with not being on the stage in the constructor.

Comment: Oh ok, I mean I'm decent at code but not an expert haha. And I know it's coded in here to make the shapes and stuff, but usually I tend to like drawing my guys and stuff. I mean I don't really know what Flash IDE is so I don't know what I'm talking about haha, but I like being able to use the timeline on occasion and draw my own guys and make their own classes and stuff =p

Comment: Cool, cool, no worries then, likely you're just running into this issue, of accessing the stage before you really have a handle on it.  I believe your options are, 1 pass the stage to the other objects that need it (via their constructor so they always have a reference to it, store as _stage locally since stage will also be preset) or 2 listen for added to stage events within the non document class objects then have them grab the stage object and do whatever they need to do (if they need to do something with the stage directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though your `Volume` class is as you said, mostly complete and self-contained.  This is good, as it will make instantiating a new instance of it within your document class easier.

Within the document, class, to instantiate a new class, you can do the following:

```
var new_volume:Volume = new Volume();
addChild(new_volume);
```

It's important to note that the `stage` does not come into scope within your `Volume` class **until you have added it to the stage from within it's parent class** (in this case, it's parent class is the document class).

So these two lines:

```
public var xPos:Number=stage.stageWidth/2;
public var yPos:Number=stage.stageHeight/2;
```

don't work, as the stage is undefined there.  To wait until you get know `stage` is defined, you can use an `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event listener.  So you can re-write your `Volume` class a bit to look more like this:

```
package {

    /* Imports here */

    public class Volume extends Sprite {
            /* Other vars here */
            public var xPos:Number;
            public var yPos:Number;

            public function Volume(){       
                    /* Other assignments that are not stage-dependant can go here */
                    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
            }

            private function onStage(e:Event):void{
                    //We remove it immediately so that it doesn't get called multiple times
                    //As the instance is added to the display list tree
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

                    xPos = stage.stageWidth/2;
                    yPos = stage.stageHeight/2;

                    /* Now that we have a reference to the stage, let's go ahead and create our slider */
                    init();
            }
```

from there you can go on with business as usual, and just alter your variable values as needed to get the class to work within the confines of your player environment/document class.

Comment: @M Sost  THANK YOUUUUU. Great explanation, worked perfect (except your onstage function the second time wasn't capitalized!!! =pp). I think I kinda understand how to implement classes a little better now. Simply just create an instance of them and make sure they are added to the stage and the functions within the class act in accordance to what has been defined. THANKSSS

Comment: Oops, good catch!  Edited to fix that. Also, I'd change that just a bit to: "Simply create an instance of them and make sure their functions within act in accordance to what has been defined." If you don't need a reference to stage (perhaps a utility class or something else that's not stage-based) then you don't need to wait until it's on the stage :).  Glad I could help!